# Matlab how to display snapshots?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
vido = videoinput('winvideo',1);
vido.FrameGrabInterval = 10;
 start(vido)
while(vido.FramesAcquired<=30)
data = getsnapshot(vido);
 imshow(data);

flushdata(vido);
end
```

Hi.I have the code above.It is working but taking place from memory for every snapshot.For example it stars 600mb,610,620...Why ? how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely **not** removing the video object when you're done.  You keep creating video objects every time you run this code, even though you grab 30 frames from the source and stop capturing after that point. As such, make sure you remove the video object when the `while` loop finishes by [`delete`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html).

In addition, you have stated that `imshow` is the reason why you keep getting an increase in memory.  It actually shouldn't, but if you're really that concerned, you can spawn a blank figure and then grab a handle to the `imshow` window.  Next, you can simply update the window for each frame you read in... so:

```
hAxes = subplot(1,1,1); % //Create a blank window and get the axes handle

%// First frame flag
firstFrame = true;

vido = videoinput('winvideo',1);
vido.FrameGrabInterval = 10;
start(vido);
while(vido.FramesAcquired<=30)
   data = getsnapshot(vido);
   if firstFrame % //If first frame, show the image and get a handle to the window
      hImage = imshow(data, 'Parent', hAxes);
      firstFrame = false;
   else
      %// Simply update the window after the first frame
      set(hImage, 'CData', data);
   end
   flushdata(vido);
end

delete(vido); %// IMPORTANT
```

Comment: No, My problem is in while loop.imshow creates a new object for every iteration.Problem is not related to vido,it is about imshow

Comment: @burakKarasoy - You didn't mention that in your problem statement.  How was I supposed to know that?  In that case, you can create a figure window for `imshow` once, then just **update** the figure with your data.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.If ı could I would up your answer.I also realized that ı have problems rest of my code so maybe imshow() was innocent.I am trying to fix it.I answered you late because of my annoying internet connection thank you again...

Comment: @burakKarasoy - I understand.  Perhaps you can show the rest of your code and we can help diagnose your problem.  I'm not sure if I have solved your problem, but if you have, consider accepting my answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you.I figured it out.This is guilty set(vido, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf); I had this beginning of my code.I should have written it.I only had flushdata(vido) after while loop.I set it after getsnapshot().1-Not using  hImage = imshow(data, 'Parent', hAxes); is a mistake also not using flushdata(vido) is a mistake.Both cause memory to be invaded more and more.Thank you again

Comment: @burakKarasoy - hahahaha, if I saw that, I would have told you what the error was immediately.... well I'm glad you found it.  Take care!